# Unable to display data from request using AngularJS

Tags: sql, angularjs

I am trying to display data fetched from an SQL table named student. I have JSON object containing data retrieved from table using PHP file. But i can't display data in my HTML file using AngularJS.
Here is my myScript.js code

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[])
          .controller("myController",function($scope,$http)
                  {
                    getData();
                    function getData(){
                        $http.post("php/display.php").success(function(data)
                         {
                            $scope.student=data.data;                                          
                          });
                    }

                     });
```

Here is my index.html file

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
      <body ng-controller="myController">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>CITY</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="stud in student">
            <td>{{stud.id}}</td>
            <td>{{stud.name}}</td>
            <td>{{stud.city}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Also response of my display.php file is json object in the form

```
[{"Id":"1","name":"Swapnil","city":"Nanded"},           
{"Id":"2","name":"Swap","city":"Nanded"},  

{"Id":"3","name":"Swapn","city":"Nanded"},  

{"Id":"4","name":"Swapni","city":"Nanded"},
{"Id":"5","name":"Swap","city":"Parbhani"}]
```

Comment: Try `$scope.student=data.data;` it will work.

Comment: Verify you are able to get data in success method, if got then share the $scope.student values

Comment: i tried    $scope.student=data.data but still unable to display resultset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the **data** object from the request **result**:

```
$http.post("php/display.php").success(function(result) {
  $scope.student = result.data;                                           
});
```